# xubuntu video rendering issue

Tags: video, xubuntu, ati

As i am playing avi videos on my newly installed Xubuntu i observe video flickering because of which i do not get optimal user experience while watching videos. I have tried multiple players as well as multiple videos but the problem persists. The flickering doesnt exist when i am playing my video on win 7.

**info**
driver:- amd radeon 4500
propriety driver activated
players tried:- mplayer, vlc

Answer (score 3):

If you have xubuntu's compositor active (only supports drop shadows and transparency), try running mplayer with `-vo gl` or `-vo gl2`. If this does not help, try turning the compositor off (settings/window manager tweaks, rightmost tab).

Comment: I find that you need to turn off the compositor for vlc to play correctly in fullscreen, but not mplayer based programs like gnome-mplayer. In general, I find that the compositor causes big problems with hardware accelerated video overlays.

Comment: Disabling the compositor made the flickering when watching DVDs go away for me :-)